# Changing font size with buttons in a specific <div>

Tags: javascript, fonts, font-size

After editing what I had to the code shared below I used the scripts below.

I edited the working file in a response below and pretty much the exact same thing worked fine..

I seem to be missing something in mine...

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the Java Script I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resizeText(multiplier) {
var elem = document.getElementById("MiddleContent");
var currentSize = elem.style.fontSize || 1;
elem.style.fontSize = ( parseFloat(currentSize) + (multiplier * 0.2)) + "em";
}
</script>
```

This is the table code:

```
<table border="0" id="MiddleContent">
<tr>
<td width="150" align="center">
<img src="../images/filler.jpg" width="146" height="104" />
</td>
<td  align="center" width="218" valign="middle">
<span style="color:#59461f; font-size:22px;">
Title of Story!
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:14px">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pellentesque tellus egestas, mauris cursus phasellus sit curabitur amet, molestias urna wisi.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And finally this is where my buttons are:

```
<div id="fontSizeButton" align="center">
<table width="96" border="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">FONT SIZE</td>
</tr>
<tr>    
<td>
<input name="reSize" type="button" value="&nbsp;+&nbsp;" onclick="resizeText(1)" />
</td>
<td align="right">
<input name="reSize2" type="button" value="&nbsp;-&nbsp;" onclick="resizeText(-1)" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I have re-tagged the question. javascript is not java+script

Answer (score 0):

Use [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById%5C) to reference the element. There is also no need to have the function 2 times for positive and negative direction, just pass in the negative number.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="foo">
    XXX
</div>
<input name="reSize" type="button" value="&nbsp;+&nbsp;" onclick="resizeText(1)" />
<input name="reSize2" type="button" value="&nbsp;-&nbsp;" onclick="resizeText(-1)" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function resizeText(multiplier) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("foo");
    var currentSize = elem.style.fontSize || 1;
    elem.style.fontSize = ( parseFloat(currentSize) + (multiplier * 0.2)) + "em";
}
```

**Running Example:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HRpw9/)

Comment: I changed a couple things in your running example to make sure i understood it somewhat, and it worked fine.  When I applied the same thing to my page it didnt seem to work.  I'm probably doing something super basic wrong and I apologize for that.

Comment: this is the java script i have

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeText(multiplier) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("MiddleContent");
    var currentSize = elem.style.fontSize || 1;
    elem.style.fontSize = ( parseFloat(currentSize) + (multiplier * 0.2)) + "em";
    }
    </script>

Comment: Sorry it wont let me post this in a better fashion as a Comment so I will edit the original question to what I have now.

Comment: You have hardcoded pixel based font sizes on elements inside, it will not magically change those when you change the size of the parent. And it is JavaScript, there is no space.

Comment: I took the hard coded font size off and it works great.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm clear on what you're asking.

If you replace `body` in your code with `getElementById("main")` where "main" is the id of your div, I think it should do what you're asking.